# Attempting to build Mave (with M2E) getting classdef error

Tags: java, maven

I've just started working with maven so if this is an idiotic or obvious question please bear with me.

I've got a soap server that I built for one of our servers, it requires things such as boneCP, slf4j, connector-java, so I added these to the POM.xml and when I just run or debug the soap server it works fine. However whenever I try to build it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpProvider
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:106)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:346)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:139)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:122)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:86)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpProvider
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
... 32 more
```

I've searched on google but cant seem to find anything relating to this issue when using maven, only when declaring the classpath manually.

Am I missing something?

sorry if this is an obvious or stupid question, as I said I'm just starting out with maven.

EDIT:
Thanks for the help!
I ran the command to check dependencies and got

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ auth ---
[INFO] com.v2.auth:auth:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compi
```

so it seems like the problem is coming from guava and logback not playing nice? so it looks like I need to find a way to exclude that slf4j version from being included in Guava?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem with Maven is that sometimes you have dependencies conflicts, especially when you inherit dependencies from a parent POM.

The parent POM might define a version of the library, and your POM define a newer one. From here, there are two possibilities:

-The class not found is included in the older version, but not in the new one, and the new is the one that is being used. In fact, this could happen without the need of conflicting dependencies to exist: you can just have included the newest version instead of the old one.

-The class not found is included in the newer version, but the dependency management causes the old version to be the one used.

Check your [dependencies map](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), and you will find if there is any conflict between versions.

Comment: So as I noted above it seems like the problem is between guava and logback trying to load two different versions of slf4j. So I figured I could exclude the version from guava and it should work, but since guava is a dependency of bonecp (I think) how could I exclude it from including slf4j?